# how i can get the selected item in my grid

Tags: wpf, grid

I'm completely new to WPF
i want to get selected element in `mygrid` its have `array of contacts objects`
i need access to the selected contact and get the `Contactid` to use in some methods like
`deleteContactByID()` when user click the delete Button and refresh the grid to hide the row is deleted

```
<Window x:Class="WPFClient.ListOFContacts"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListOFContacts" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="450" Width="700" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFClient.PhoneBookServiceReference" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="contactViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:Contact, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource contactViewSource}" Name="myGrid" AllowDrop="True" ShowGridLines="False">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="387" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="contactDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" SelectionChanged="contactDataGrid_SelectionChanged">

             <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Header="Name" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="emailColumn" Header="Email" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="phoneNumberColumn" Header="Phone Number" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>



                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Header="Address" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Address}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="mobilColumn" Header="Mobil" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mobil}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Delete" Header="Delete" Width="auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="btnDelete">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the `SelectedItem` property of the DataGrid to a property in your DataContext type. And on Delete handler you can just access your type's property to get the selected contact. In your case:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem={Binding SelectedContact} AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="387" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="contactDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" SelectionChanged="contactDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
```

If you have set the `DataContext` to a `ViewModel` then you need to have a property `SelectedContact` in your ViewModel class as you might have done for other properties.

```
public Contact SelectedContact
{
    get; set; // Calling the NotifyPropertyChanged 
}
```

Then in your handler you just need to access the SelectedContact proeprty to get the selected contact.

```
void handler()
{
    var selectedContact = SelectedContact;
    var contactId = selectedContact.ContactId; 
}
```

I hope this clears your doubts.